# i try to import a sound in my flash game. It shows "one or more files were not imported because there were problems reading them". Help me

Tags: flash, actionscript, audio

i try to import a sound in my flash game. It shows "one or more files were not imported because there were problems reading them". Help me

Answer (score 0):

Either the file is corrupt (some programs handle that better than others), or the file format is simply not supported.

Try and do a google search on something like "reencode audio file" or "transcode audio file", you should be able to find a free tool.

Answer (score 0):

What codec are you using? WAV, MP3, AAC, etc? I have found that sometimes using an MP3 encoded on a PC will not import properly on a Mac and vise versa.